Is the image of an internal hom-object under a monoidal functor (between rigid tensor categories) an internal hom-object?
Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ and $(\mathcal{C}',\otimes')$ be rigid tensor categories, and let $(F,c):(\mathcal{C},\otimes) \to (\mathcal{C}',\otimes')$ be a monoidal functor, where $c_{X,Y}:F(X) \otimes' F(Y) \simeq F(X \otimes Y)$.
Am I correct that $F(X^{\vee} \otimes Y)$ is an internal-hom object of $\mathcal{C}'$? Does this in turn mean that the evaluation-morphism for $F(X^{\vee} \otimes Y) \otimes FX$ is $F(\text{ev}_{X,Y}) \circ c$ and that $F(\text{ev}_{X,Y}) \circ c = \text{ev}_{FX,FY} \circ \gamma \otimes \text{id}$ for some unique morphism $\gamma$? If the answer is yes, how does one show this? I suspect that $F(X^{\vee} \otimes Y)$ being an internal-hom object of the target-category of $F$ follows from the fact that $F$ preserves duals. I know how to show that $F$ preserves duals (see e.g. chapter 3 of Categories for Quantum Theory), but I am not sure how $F(X^{\vee} \otimes Y)$ being an internal hom-object follows from $F$ preserving duals.
I am not entirely sure what universal property characterizes an internal hom-object; is it enough that we have a natural isomorphism $\text{Hom}(Z \otimes X,Y) \simeq \text{Hom}(Z,\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y))$? So $T$ is an internal $\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y)$-object, if $\text{Hom}(Z,T) \simeq \text{Hom}(Z \otimes X,Y)$? Does this in turn mean that if $T$ is naturally isomorphic to $\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y)$, then $T$ is an internal $\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y)$-object? If the answer here is positive, I might have a way to show this, otherwise, I am quite lost.
Edit: Note that we have $X^{\vee} \otimes Y \cong \underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y)$ if $\mathcal{C}$ is rigid (I don't recall if this isomorphism is natural, but I believe the answer is yes).

An internal hom object between what and what?

It doesn't make sense to say that $T$ is naturally isomorphic to $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X, Y)$, because $T$ is not a functor.

You are of course right @NaïmFavier, regarding $T$.

For any objects $X, Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $F(X^\vee \otimes Y)$ is indeed the internal hom object $[FX, FY]$ in $\mathcal{C}'$. This means that the functor $\mathcal{C}'(- \otimes FX, FY)$ is represented by $F(X^\vee \otimes Y)$, which follows from preservation of duality:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}'(- \otimes FX, FY) &\cong \mathcal{C}'(-, (FX)^\vee \otimes FY) \\
&\cong \mathcal{C}'(-, F(X^\vee) \otimes FY) \\
&\cong \mathcal{C}'(-, F(X^\vee \otimes Y))
\end{align}
$$

How do evaluation-morphisms between internal hom-objects (if there are more than one) relate to eachother? E.g. we have $[X,\mathbf{1}] \otimes Y \cong [X,Y]$ with associated evaluation-morphisms; how are they related? This relates to my question. Apart from that, as always, thanks a ton for answering :)

They are related by making the obvious triangle commute, as in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4946212.

Yeah that is what I thought; I could not find a way to show it though. I was thinking about Yoneda embedding as you mentioned in your other answer; but at first I thiught that this would identify them as the same object. Again thanks a lot for your help, all of your answers have been super helpful!

Correction: thought*
